# Ошибка в легенде при построении горизонтального барчарта (plt.barh)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, визуализация

#### Исходные данные

Датафрейм размером: 350677 rows × 20 columns.
Колонки: курсы, модули в составе курсов, уроки в составе модулей, id студентов, их личные данные и прочее. В работе используется Jupyter Notebook, библиотеки Pandas, Numpy, Matplotlib.

#### Задача

Постройте горизонтальный bar-chart, отражающий количество студентов на каждом курсе. График должен иметь заголовок. Значения должны быть отсортированы. Цвет столбцов должен содержать информацию о сфере, к которой относится курс (то есть нужна легенда). Прозрачность должна стоять на отметке 0.1. На график должна быть нанесена линия медианы. У медианы должен быть свой цвет. Рамки у графика быть не должно

#### Проблема

Привожу код, который я использую

```
students_on_course = main.groupby('title').student_id.nunique()

my_color = matplotlib.colors.get_named_colors_mapping()

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.barh(students_on_course.index, students_on_course.sort_values(ascending=True),
         color=list(my_color)[:14], alpha=0.1, label=students_on_course.index)

median_soc = int(students_on_course.median())
plt.axvline(x=median_soc, ls='--', color='blue', label='Медианная численность студентов')

plt.title('Количество студентов на курсах')
plt.yticks([])
plt.box(on=None)
plt.legend(loc='lower right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка? Почему в легенду не переносятся значения в соответствии с цветом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать так. Проще использовать Seaborn, он многое умеет "из коробки", в отличие от Matplotlib.

```
ax = plt.barh(students_on_course.index, students_on_course.sort_values(ascending=True),
         color=list(my_color)[:14], alpha=0.1)

...

plt.legend(ax.patches,students_on_course.index, loc='lower right')
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я попробовал, но, к сожалению, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @Ostap_Penderman Есть возможность показать хотя бы несколько строк исходных данных (а лучше весь DataFrame)? На пальцах тяжело гадать, а сходу сгенерить подходящие данные, чтобы попробовать варианты не соображу как.

Comment: Вот ссылка на ipynb файл в google collaboration: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jCAnAbyM5AS2EIaCNEAsFt-TElqON2SA?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ostap_Penderman Код то я вижу, а файлы с данными - не вижу

Comment: прошу прощения, вот ссылка на google disk. Там папка с файлами: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1B4cy4VeGDQ6LUAgiPTDKd4w6I9MH10C1?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ostap_Penderman Поменял ответ. Попробуйте так. Не знаю - то что нужно это или нет, но если что хотя бы принцип сам можно использовать.

Comment: добрый день! Большое спасибо, всё сработало. Можете в двух словах объяснить, что и как произошло?

Comment: Ну если я сам правильно понял, чтобы легенда правильно показывалась надо сопоставить лейблы элементам графика, а как вы пытались получалось установить легенду сразу для всего графика, так оно не умеет правильно сопоставлять. Вот библиотека Seaborn сама такие вещи делает, попробуйте её как-нибудь. Хотя понимать как работает Matplotlib тоже полезно, чтобы регулировать всё на низком уровне.